# Adding Fruit Together.

Tags: arithmetic

[image: fruit math]!

If the image above doesn't show, the equation could be rendered as follows:

$$\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}=4$$

How would you go about solving this? Trying to do LCD and substituting does not seem to work well.

Comment: Well, it is apparent that this problem cannot have **exactly** one solution: if $(a,b,c)$ is a solution, then $(ka,kb,kc)$  with $k\ne0$ is a solution as well.

Comment: Finding *all* values is a little daunting. However, the question asks for any values. If you'd like to just come up with one or two solutions choose any apple and banana (not both zero) you'd like and solve for pineapple.

Comment: It's only one equation, with three unknowns - the system is likely wildly underdetermined. Try picking anything you like for two and solve for the other. I tried setting apple to 0 and pineapple to 1, and got an irrational number for banana (OK, but probably not ideal).

Comment: Oh, and I suppose apple and banana should not be additive inverses either.

Comment: The usual statement of the problem requires the unknowns to be positive integers. See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/questions/278747/is-the-set-of-integers-of-the-form-a-bcb-acc-ab-computable

Comment: Related, with some more information on the set of solutions: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779545/ask-for-the-rational-roots-of-fracabc-fracbac-fraccab-4

Answer (score 0):

Consider the case where $apple = 0$ and $banana = 1$. Denote the pineapple by $p$. Then we have,

$$\frac{0}{1+p}+\frac{1}{0+p}+\frac{p}{1+0} = 4$$
$$\frac{1}{p}+p = 4$$
$$1+p^2 = 4p$$
$$p^2-4p+1 = 0$$
$$p = \frac{4\pm \sqrt{16-4}}{2} = 2\pm \sqrt{3}$$

Thus $$(apple=0, banana=1, pineapple= 2+\sqrt{3})$$ $$(apple=0, banana=1, pineapple= 2-\sqrt{3})$$and  are two possible solutions in the real numbers.