# How to show a rational polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[a,b,c]$?

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry

> How to show that a rational polynomial is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[a,b,c]$? For example, I try to show this polynomial $$p(a,b,c)=a(a+c)(a+b)+b(b+c)(b+a)+c(c+a)(c+b)-4(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)(*)$$ is irreducible, where $a,b,c\in \mathbb{Q}$.

The related problem is [Ask for the rational roots of $\frac{a}{b+c}+\frac{b}{a+c}+\frac{c}{a+b}=4.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2779545/ask-for-the-rational-roots-of-fracabc-fracbac-fraccab-4). Could I consider the points $(*)$ intersect with $L_{\infty}$ are three? $L_{\infty}$ is the infinity line in a projective space $\mathbb{C}P^2$.

Comment: Irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[a,b,c]$?

Comment: @mathworker21 Yes!

Comment: It doesn't make sense to ask about *irreducibility* of $p(a,b,c)$ as a polynomial if $a,b,c\in \mathbb Q$, because assigning rational values to $p(a,b,c)$ makes it a rational number in $\mathbb Q$, and hence a polynomial only in the sense of being a constant term.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose contrary that $p(a,b,c)$ is reducible over $\mathbb{Q}$.  You can write $p(a,b,c)$ as
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3(b+c)a^2-3(c+a)b^2-3(a+b)c^2-5abc\,.$$
It suffices to regard $p(a,b,c)$ as a polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_3$ (why?).  Over $\mathbb{F}_3$, 
$$p(a,b,c)=a^3+b^3+c^3+abc=a^3+(bc)a+(b+c)^3\,.$$
Since $p(a,b,c)$ is homogeneous of degree $3$ and reducible,  it has a linear factor $a+ub+vc$ for some $u,v\in\mathbb{F}_3$.  Clearly, we must have $ub+vc \mid (b+c)^3$, whence $u=v=1$ or $u=v=-1$.  However, both choices are impossible via direct computation.

Comment: Very nice:+1 ${}{}{}$

Comment: To show that the polynomial $p(a,b,c)$ in the indeterminates $a,b,c$ is irreducible over $\mathbb F_3$ it suffices to prove that the curve  $V(p)\subset \mathbb P^2_{\mathbb F_3 }$ given by $p(a,b,c)=0$ is smooth. But this is clear because the system of equations $p(a,b,c)=bc=ca=ab$ has no non-trivial solution over any extension of $\mathbb F_3$.

Comment: What is the $\mathbb{F}_{3}$?

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg What is the $\mathbb{F}_{3}$ and $\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{F}_{3}}$?

Comment: Dear Tinzoe-Yui, the notation $\mathbb F_3=\mathbb Z/(3)$ stands for the field with 3 elements. And  $\mathbb P^2_{\mathbb F_3}$ is the projective plane over that field. My comment is only a little variant for users interested in algebraic geometry. It is certainly not indispensable for understanding Batominovski's excellent and  purely algebraic proof.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg  Schinzel's book has a concrete test. I put an answer. Note that Schinzel is talking about reducing over the complexes, while the question is about the rationals.

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg Thanks for your explanation. Is $\mathbb{Z}/(3)$ =$3\mathbb{Z}$ right?

Comment: The notation $\mathbb Z/(3)$ means the quotient field $\mathbb Z/3\mathbb Z$ with three elements, not the infinite ideal $3\mathbb Z\subset \mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 3):

To ask about complete (three linear factor) reducibility over the complexes, we take the Hessian matrix of second partials. The entries are linear in the named variables. Next, let $\Delta$ be the determinant of the Hessian. This $\Delta$ is once again a cubic form. The original cubic (homogeneous) ternary form factors completely if and only if $\Delta $ is a constant multiple of it. I have finished this first test, your cubic does not factor completely.

More difficult if the cubic might be a linear times an irreducible quadratic. In that case, there is still a conclusive test:

[image]

For your problem, the coefficients in order from $0$ to $9$ are
$$ 1,-3,-3,-3,-5,-3,1,-3,-3,1 $$
where the best looking diagram is a triangle as in bowling. The $-5$ refers to $-5abc \; ,$ the $1$s refer to $a^3,b^3,c^3 \; .$

Alright, I wote a little program to correctly type the 8 by ten matrix, then put that into gp-Pari. The original polynomial is irreducible over the complex numbers.

---

```
? 
?  sch = [ 0, 3, 0, -6, -6, 0, -3, -5, -3, 0; 0, 0, 3, 0, -6, -6, 0, -3, -5, -3; -3, -6, -5, 3, -6, -3, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, 0, -3, 0, -6, -5, 0, 3, -6, -3; -3, -5, -6, -3, -6, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0; 0, -3, 0, -5, -6, 0, -3, -6, 3, 0; 1, 0, -3, 3, 0, -3, -2, 3, 0, 1; 1, -3, 0, -3, 0, 3, 1, 0, 3, -2]
%25 = 
[ 0  3  0 -6 -6  0 -3 -5 -3  0]

[ 0  0  3  0 -6 -6  0 -3 -5 -3]

[-3 -6 -5  3 -6 -3  0  0  0  0]

[ 0  0 -3  0 -6 -5  0  3 -6 -3]

[-3 -5 -6 -3 -6  3  0  0  0  0]

[ 0 -3  0 -5 -6  0 -3 -6  3  0]

[ 1  0 -3  3  0 -3 -2  3  0  1]

[ 1 -3  0 -3  0  3  1  0  3 -2]

? matrank(sch)
%26 = 8
? 
? 
?
```

---